# How do you get final sale price to populate using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using javascript to create a simple calculator. Ideally I want something that works like DSW.com has.
[image]

I would like to be able to enter the amount of the product, then click a button that has your discount on it. And populate a span tag or something similar with the final price.

Any sort of guidance would be helpful.

```js
function calc() {
        var i = document.getElementById("saleprice").value;
        var p = document.getElementById("percentoff").value;
        var o = (i / 100) * p;
        document.getElementById("finalprice").value = i - o;
    }
```

```html
<form action="javascript:calc()"> Sale Price:
        <input type="text" id="saleprice" />
        <br /> Percent Off:
        <input type="radio" name="percentoff" id="percentoff" value="50" />50%
        <br /> Percent Off:
        <input type="radio" name="percentoff" id="percentoff" value="30" />30%
        <br /> Percent Off:
        <input type="radio" name="percentoff" id="percentoff" value="20" />20%
        <br /> Final Price:
        <input type="text" id="finalprice" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" /> </form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply the full price by the percent off: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/07fa46nu/

```
function sale(percent){
  var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
  var sale = price * percent;
  document.getElementById('sale').value = sale;
}
```

HTML:

```
Full price: <input type="text" id="price">
<br>
<button onclick="sale(.5)">
  50%
</button>
<button onclick="sale(.3)">
  30%
</button>
<button onclick="sale(.25)">
  25%
</button>
<button onclick="sale(.15)">
  15%
</button>
<button onclick="sale(0)">
  0% :(
</button>
<br>
Your price:
<input type="text" id="sale">
```